# Laravel 5.1 redirect within a transaction block

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have a set of delete statements in my Laravel 5.1 application that I have put inside a transaction.

I had my code like the following and was trying to return to the same page. But I was getting a **blank page**. My routes.php is fine.

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($foo, $bar, $request)  
{   
    // Delete from table abc
    $deletedFoo = DB::delete('delete from abc where id = ' .  $foo);

    // Delete from table xyz
    $deletedBar = DB::delete('delete from xyz where id = ' .  $bar);

    // Shows blank page
    $request->session()->flash('changes_saved', 'Success! All your changes were saved.');
    return back();

});
```

However, if I put the return starement outside the DB::transaction block it works fine.

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($foo, $bar)    
{   
    // Delete from table abc
    $deletedFoo = DB::delete('delete from abc where id = ' .  $foo);

    // Delete from table xyz
    $deletedBar = DB::delete('delete from xyz where id = ' .  $bar);
});

// Goes back to the page with the message
$request->session()->flash('changes_saved', 'Success! All your changes were saved.');
return back();
```

I tried various things before I realized I need to put the redirect outside the transaction. But why? I am new to Laravel and bit confused here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use return like this:

```
return DB::transaction(function () {
    ...
    return back();
});
```

To understand it let's break the code:

```
$transaction = function ($foo, $bar, $request)  
{
    // ...
    return back();
}

return DB::transaction($transaction); // return is required here
```

Unless you return the  `DB::transaction` call to your controller class then it'll not be returned. So, use return like this:

```
public function controllerMethod()
{
    return DB::transaction(...); // You must return
}
```

So, just put the `return` keywork before your `DB::transaction(...)`. Also, it would be better if you controll the execution flow from outside the transaction, for example:

```
$result = DB::transaction(function () use ($foo, $bar) {
    // ...
    return true;
});

if($result === true) {
    return back();
}
```

Comment: If I look at your first snippet, how would you put your return back(); .... sorry if that's a dumb question. But don't see how would you redirect if you have it like this.

Comment: The answer is very clear, just put `return` before the `DB::transaction()` like  `DB::transaction(...);`, rest of your code will remain same.

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot.